# How to designate sender Name in Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Gmail, the following email address

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'no-reply@example.com'
end
```

Turns into this (the second item)

[image]

Is there anyway to have the "from" address be "no-reply" but have the from name be something more meaningful?

I have noticed my email form SumAll renders as from "SumAll" but with a different reply to address as below:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?SumAll?= <mailing@sumall.com>
```

Any idea how to manage this with Action Mailer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out section 2.3.4 of the [ActionMailer documentation.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name)

Specifically:

> 2.3.4 Sending Email With Name
>
> Sometimes you wish to show the name of the person instead of just
>   their email address when they receive the email. The trick to doing
>   that is to format the email address in the format "Full Name ".

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  email_with_name = "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>"
  mail(to: email_with_name, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
```

If it's the same sender for all emails in your mailer, I'd suggest trying `default from: "Some name <some-email@example.com>"` - this should work as well.

Comment: I wonder if this will work in the default from field? I'll try it

Comment: Yes, it should work there as well.  The above is more of a dynamic solution.  If all emails come from the same sender, `default from` would be the preferred solution.  I'll update my answer.